# Image Load From url getting slow system android

Tags: java, json, eclipse, android-fragments, android-imageview

Whenever I want to run my code on mobile, mobile is slow and image load is also slow I think there is size issue so please tell me about that how to get small size of image .
here is my code.

```
public class TopRatedFragment extends Fragment {

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    private static String url_all_products = "http://3ilogics.org/vid/get_all_products.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "price";
    private static final String TAG_IMG = "images_url";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;
    JSONArray products2 = null;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated, container,
                false);
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        try {
            products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);



            //sd=json.getJSONObject(TAG_PRODUCTS).length();
            for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);


            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HorizontalListView listview = (HorizontalListView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        return rootView;


    }

    private static String[] dataObjects = new String[] { "Text #1", "Text #2",
            "Text #3", "Text #4", "Text #5", "Text #6", "Text #7", "Text #8",
            "Text #9", "Text #10" };

    private BaseAdapter mAdapter = new BaseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return TopRatedFragment.this.products.length();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View retval = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.viewitem, null);
            TextView title = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.title);
            ImageView title2 = (ImageView) retval.findViewById(R.id.image);
            String img=null;

            try {
                //Log.d("sda",products.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                title.setText(products.getJSONObject(position).getString(TAG_NAME));
                img=products.getJSONObject(position).getString(TAG_IMG);
                title2.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(img));
                System.gc();
            } 

            catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            //Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());
            return retval;
        }

    };
    public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String img) {
        try {

            URL url = new URL(img);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

            return myBitmap;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: you should get exception while running this code as network calls can not execute in UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use an async task for executing such operations, something like this: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Comment: How to use async task can you please explain it through any sample code

Comment: @user3345828 you should be able to find millions of samples/tutorials for AsyncTask if you simply search for it...